# print report on model by javascript spcel design error?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am using model report print spcel design report but result is not show missing javascript code. i have no idea so please check it now sir and share me valuable idea...

```
var win ='<table class="table table-bordered table-sm">';
win+='<tbody>';
win+='<tr>';
win+='<th scope="row">Sr. No.</th>';
win+='<th>Penalty Questions</th>';
win+='<th scope="row">Marked</th>';
win+='<th>No. of Units</th>';
win+='<th scope="row">Price</th>';
win+='<th>Total Amount</th>';
win+='</tr>';
//--------------------error part -----------------------here----------
if(global_res1){
    var res = global_res1;
    for(i=0;i<res['quest'].length;i++) {
        win+='<tr><td>'+i+'</td><td>'+res['quest'][i]['quest']+'</td>';
        if(res['quest'][i]['marked']=="Y") {
            var tot_amt = res['quest'][i]['amount']*res['quest'][i]['unit'];
            win+='<td><i class="fa fa-check-square-o bg-success"></td><td>'+res['quest'][i]['unit']+'</td><td>'+res['quest'][i]['amount']+'</td><td>'+tot_amt+'</td>';
            sum+=tot_amt;
        } else {
            win+='<td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>';
        }
        win+='</tr>';
    }
    win+='<tr><td> </td><th>Total amount</th><td></td><td></td><td></td><th>'+sum+'</th></tr>';     
}
//-----------------------------------------------
win+='</tbody>';
win+='</table>';
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: It would be great if you post full code and make it reproducible here

Comment: missing part is not working syntax error?

Comment: The problem is, that this question has no error message and `global_res1` is unknown to us. `Uncaught ReferenceError: global_res1 is not defined` is all I get. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), because we're programmers and not clairvoyants.